# how to find column space of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

> Find the column space of matrix $A$ if
>   $$ A= \begin{pmatrix}10 & 2 & 3 \\
> 2 & 4 & 6 \\
> 2 & 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$$

This is what I've done so far but I'm not sure if it is correct.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      10&2&3&x\\
      2&4&6&y\\2&4&6&z
    \end{array}
\right] $$

reduced down to
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      10&2&3&x\\
      0&-18&-27&x-5y\\0&0&0&z-y
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Does this mean the column space is $z - y = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Do row reduction on the transpose of the given matrix to get the row space of the transpose which will inturn give you the column space of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

note that the first two columns of the matrix are linearly independent vectors, but the third is $3/2$ the second.